# How to know if your pc is being monitored by employer?

Tags: monitoring

I know in big cooperation they can monitor our computer at anytime. But as users how do we know that we are being monitored or not. Is there any way of knowing it?

Does the icons show below shows any indications. From chronicle order Dame ware, Synaptic Pointing Device and ultra VNC [image][image]

Comment: Are you talking about your private computer or about a company computer with monitoring by the same company?

Comment: Company Computer, handed to each staff.

Comment: Well it completely depends on what 'monitoring' you are talking about. You would have signed something to say that the company can check/monitor anything to do with company equipment however in practice it's a lot harder to execute. Internet Traffic and Emails are two easier things to monitor, files on the machine and (if a laptop) what happens outside the office are again harder to find out but not impossible if they have enough reason to suspect and check.

Comment: Unless you have complete and exclusive control over the hardware and the software installed on it, it can be very hard to tell that you are being watched and it is impossible to be sure that you are *not* being watched. Any tool used for monitoring may just be better at hiding than the tools you can use to look for it. That aside: IMHO it does not make sense to monitor your employees and not tell them about it. If you tell them you can prevent unwanted behaviour, if you don't you can only discipline them afterwards.

Comment: run a command prompt (start, "cmd", enter) and type this command
WMIC /OUTPUT:"%userprofile%\desktop\ProcessList.txt" process get Caption,Executablepath
then you should have a file ProcessList.txt on your desktop, so just open it, edit your question here and paste it there. Then we can check what is running on your system and if something looks like monitoring ;)

Comment: @Vitas tried nothing happened. Is this right, WMIC /OUTPUT:"%userprofile%\desktop\ProcessList.txt"

Comment: Sarenya the command starts with WMIC and ends with Executablepath. Just read properly what I write ;) And write here what exactly happens. Is there that file on your desktop after executing this command or not?

Comment: invalid file name

Comment: type      echo %userprofile%      and send here result please

Comment: The result is c:\User\pnasguna

Comment: Well then I am not sure why it does not work. Try WMIC /OUTPUT:"c:\User\pnasguna\desktop\ProcessList.txt"

Comment: @Vitas I have added the command promt pic at the question

Comment: of course you forgot the space after wmic before / ;) But maybe it will not help...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a very open ended question with no real answer.

It depends on the type of monitoring being implemented.

If they are looking over your shoulder, they may be doing so using software like SCCM or LANDesk.. While LANDesk has a system tray icon which glows white/yellow when you are being watched, SCCM doesn't but does have an optional "RDP" style bar which lets you kow.. and the smart solution doesn't have any form of identification.

If they are monitoring internet usage, they may be doing so by using a proxy server - in which case, you will have absolutely no way to know whatsoever.  You could check your proxy server in internet explorer to see if you go through one, and that would give an indication.. but they could just set your default gateway on a smaller network to a proxy server and before you know it, you have no way of knowing again.

They could be using system auditing and event logging - in which case, you may or may not be able to tell by checking the event logs for your PC (look at the security log for events) which could give an indication.

If you have company mail, the administrator and some managers probably have access to  your mailbox in some form.

You could possibly try looking at a nestat report for your machine, but this will just list connections to your PC (websites, mail servers, company app servers etc.. but may also list a management server)

Generally, smaller companies in my experience won't monitor staff PCs very closely for app usage etc as the time required and the man power just isn't there, but that doesn't mean they can't do it or won't do it if they have reason to do so... but it can be a costly thing to implement.

Comment: Is there a way they could mirror image my desktop, without me even noticing it. Because they have this remote access that allows them to take control my laptop and install any application. But before they have access I need to click the accept button for them to enter my laptop. I have added a picture in my question.

Comment: VNC Is how they will be connecting to your machne.  See https://www.realvnc.com/  What do you mean by mirror image?  If you mean take a copy of everything... you don't need VNC to do that, they could do it through a simple network share